# Highlight specific words in a RichTextBox

Tags: richtextbox, vb.net-2010, highlighting

How can i do this: I press on a button and then it finds every occurrence of the word let's say "test" and changes the word's fore color to aqua...

```
txtText.Find("dim")
txtText.SelectionColor = Color.Aqua
```

If i do this it only finds the first occurrence, makes it aqua and if i press it again it turns all the text like that. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code, to do that:

First you need button(FindBUT), and RichTextBox(TextBox)

```
Public Class Research

Private Sub FindBUT_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FindBUT.Click
    'Check button text
    If FindBUT.Text = ("Find ""dim""") Then
        'Return all text color to black
        TextBox.ForeColor = Color.Black
        'Find "dim" word
        TextBox.Find("dim")
        TextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Aqua
        'change button text to ("Find all")
        FindBUT.Text = ("Find all")
        'Check button text
    ElseIf FindBUT.Text = ("Find all") Then
        'change all text color to Aqua
        TextBox.ForeColor = Color.Aqua
        'change button text to ("Find ""dim"" ")
        FindBUT.Text = ("Find ""dim""")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class